# How to load test data from external database

Tags: mysql, spring, maven, model-view-controller, dbunit

I am having a maven based spring MVC project. In which I am using hibernate3-maven-plugin, In developer profile I have set "dbunit.operation.type" to be CLEAN_INSERT.
When I perform clean and build operation it drops database and create fresh tables using hbm2ddl mapping.

Now, when I run test cases I need to create test data using xml file which is pain full. 
Instead, I want to load test data in local database from another database instance like QA or UAT.

Can anyone specify how can I load test data in maven at run time when I perform a build operation from another data source?

Thanks!

Comment: You understand that doing this would make your build dependent on a specific database instance being available? Your build would stop being portable. Although it is a pain, explicitly capturing your assumptions about the data is not a bad thing. Apologies for the lecture.

Comment: I can move along with the dependency that's not the issue...but, I do not want to waste my time writing test data...do you have any idea about how to do this using "dbunit-maven-plugin" ? I want to skip specifying a source file like "<src>src/test/resources/test-data.xml</src>" to load test data. Rather, I want to specify a datasource from where I can load data in my local database for testing.